# Pyccuracy selenium-server.jar has 22 bytes?

Tags: python, selenium, pyccuracy

There must be something wrong, it has only 22 bytes and of course says it's invalid jar when I try to run it. Downloaded from this link:

https://github.com/heynemann/pyccuracy/wiki/Quick-Start

Which is official Pyccuracy document.

Comment: I get an error from GH: `Error: blob is too big` - that's 22b ;)

Comment: 22 26 Jun 15:36 selenium-server.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I got the one directly from selenium website and it works with Pyccuracy.

http://seleniumhq.org/download/

Answer (score 1):

Try to download a zipball (https://github.com/heynemann/pyccuracy/zipball/1.2.46) - `selenium-server.jar` is there under `lib`. 17MB.

Comment: Thanks. The server _seems_ to be working, when I run 'pyccuracy_console -u http://google.com' it launches firefox but then nothing happens. Maybe there's something wrong with my installation.

Comment: Maybe thats a content of another question.

Comment: No, I think it did have to do something with the server. Check my answer, I downloaded it from other source and it worked.